# Load image tag before Video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way or method by which we can load all image tags, before video tags are loaded, in HTML?

Comment: put them before video tags in order then...

Comment: Some images are before video tag and some after it. But i want to load all images first. I think there migh be some jquery function of it . I google it also but cannot find any code

Comment: so that means there is nothing like that you are searching...?

Comment: Ia m searchinf for some kind of jquery code. But cannot find it and i think it is possible with jquery also. I am trying bu cannot find. That's why I raise discussion here so that we can get solution of it

Comment: Yes it's possible with javascript/jquery, but may be possible without. Are the videos loaded from a source different to the images? If so they'll load at the same time, so you may need a JS solution.

Comment: Yes they video is from different server and what will be jquery solution of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images and videos come from different sources, so they will load synchronously and we must wait until images load before videos load...

To do this with jQuery we use `$(window).load` similar to how DOM ready is used, which waits until everything in the markup has loaded.

You've given no HTML and no info about how you include the videos so I'll create a simple example using the video tag. You can apply the logic to another method.

```
<!-- Images are not changed, as you want them to load anyway -->
<img src="/images/someimage.jpg" alt="Some image" />
<img src="/images/someotherimage.jpg" alt="Some other image" />

<!-- Videos are pending, replace src with data-src -->
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source data-src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source data-src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

jQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // this will not execute until images have loaded
    // find video > source tags
    $('video source').each(function(){
        // set the src of them from the data we stored
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
    });

    // or if you prefer
    //$('video source').attr('src', function(){ return $(this).data('src'); });

});
```

Comment: Great answer to what the OP has asked for.  However cautionary note for others - if a user wants to view your video and has to wait for some images to timeout or load slowly, then you might not be offering the best experience.

Answer (score 0):

in JS create a new image element with a src equal to the src you want to use in your img element in the HTML.  No need to ever put this image element in the DOM.  The browser will then cache the image, ready to be recalled from the cache when your HTML request the same src later on.

so something like this:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "/your/image/path";
```

Comment: But they have many and a video tag. Can you show how they would show them, after not putting the image element in the DOM. They do want that element to show eventually...

Comment: Sorry @Popnoodles don't see what you mean? if you're asking how to then display in the site - just a normal <img> tag will do; but as the src will be the same as what is used in the JS, the browser will load from the cache rather than the server.

Comment: A full answer to the question would demonstrate this. But in your example thus far, if the images exist in HTML, they will begin to load BEFORE the JS script loads, and before the JS is executed, so them being "cached" will have no effect as they already exist and are therefore not cached. Unless you're suggesting the user must visit another page first which is unreasonable.

Comment: AFAIK if you put the script before the images, the script will request the images first and hence cache them. Am I wrong?

Comment: Script tags inline with your markup are executed synchronously with the page loading, so you may get away with it I guess.  But even still, the images are coming from **a source different to the videos** so the videos may still load first with this method.

Comment: I'm just pointing out why it won't work. We need each other to do that!

Comment: Good point you edited in.  Your solution is better for what the OP asked for.